# Electric Potential due to an ellipsoid

Tags: electrostatics, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

Recently I came across the following problem:

Suppose $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ is an ellipse with surface charge density $\sigma=\sigma_0\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)$ where $\theta$ is the angle with the $z-$ axis and $\phi$ is with the $x-$ axis. Find the potential and multipole moments at a point far away from the ellipse.

**My approach:**

My initial idea was to first parametrize the ellipse as $(a\sin(\theta')\cos(\phi'),b\sin(\theta')\sin(\phi'),c\cos(\theta'))$ and then calculate $\theta,\phi$ in terms of these coordinates. I then did the coordinate transform $x\to\frac{x}{a},y\to\frac{y}{b},z\to\frac{z}{c}$ to convert it to the sphere case where you can find the potential and multipole moments using spherical harmonics. But the whole calculation is messy because you have to find the fundamental vector product and all those stuff for the coordinate change and the expression for the angles in terms of these coordinates.

So my question is whether there is a simpler approach to this problem without going through these computations that makes better use of the symmetry of the system.

N.B: I am reposting this with more details because my previous post got taken down due to lack of details.

Comment: If there was a problem with the original post then you should edit the original post with more information, editing a question will automatically put it in review queues. If there were comments on the original post you can engage in asking what might be needed to make he post better. Also if you deleted to repost, this affects your ability to ask questions negatively in the future.